# How to find the number of msb bits common between two binary numbers

Tags: binary-operations

Im trying to find the number of bits common between two binary numbers starting from MSB -> LSB. For example, I'm taking a set of binary numbers of 4 bits each i.e., 0 -> 15.

- I'm trying to find the number of common bits between 8(1000) and
  12(1100). Starting from msb we see that there is only one common bit.
  hence answer should be (1)
- 0(0000) and 15(1111) = 0
- 10(1010) and 11(1011) = 3
- 6(0110) and 8(1000) = 0

Is there a formula to do this? Or should it be brute forced by checking each bit when writing code?

Comment: What are msb and lsb? And if you're using a computer, look for "bitwise xor". It will get you part of the way.

Comment: (Bitwise xnor is actually more correct, sorry about that. I would think you find information on both in more or less the same place.)

Comment: @Arthur I believe it is "most significant bit" and "least significant bit".

Comment: @postmortes MSB is the left most digit and LSB is the right most digit

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for pointing this out. But do I still have to look for every bit which is '1' after doing xnor. Taking 10(1010) and 11(1011). XNOR(1010,1011) gives 1110.

Comment: @Bhargav Yes, from there you have to count the 1's. As I said, it will get you part of the way.